# Haskell Binary tree with key-value

Tags: algorithm, haskell, binary-search-tree

I want to build binary tree with key - value leafs with tuple (k,v).

My code:

```
data Tree k v = EmptyTree 
                | Node (k, v) (Tree k v) (Tree k v)
                deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Read)

emptyTree :: (k,v) -> Tree k v  
emptyTree (k,v) = Node (k, v) EmptyTree EmptyTree

treeInsert :: (Ord k) => (k,v) -> Tree k v -> Tree k v
treeInsert (k,v) EmptyTree = emptyTree (k, v)
treeInsert (a, b) (Node (k,v) left right) 
        | a == k = (Node (a,b) left right)
        | a < k = (Node (a, b) (treeInsert (a, b) left) right)   
        | a > k = (Node (a, b) left (treeInsert (a, b) right))
```

Now i'm trying to fill this tree:

```
fillTree :: Int -> Tree k v -> Tree k v
fillTree x tree = treeInsert (x, x) tree
```

But I get this error:

```
Couldn't match type `v' with `Int'
      `v' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for fillTree :: Int -> Tree k v -> Tree k v
```

What's the cause and how can I fix it?

Comment: In situations like this, it can be helpful to remove the type signature, load the file in GHCi, and see what the compiler *thinks* the type should be.

Comment: `emptyTree` is a really bad name for that function, as everybody would expect that it returns an `EmptyTree`. A better name would something like `singleton` or `singleNode`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your type is either too general or too specific. It should be

```
fillTree :: Int -> Tree Int Int -> Tree Int Int
```

or

```
fillTree :: (Ord a) => a -> Tree a a -> Tree a a
```

Your original declaration was trying to insert `(Int, Int)` into a `Tree k v` *for any `k`, `v`*. It was saying that no matter what kind of tree you have, we can insert a pair of `Int`s in it. This is clearly nonsense, and as your signature for `treeInsert` indicates, only pairs of type `(k, v)` can be inserted into a `Tree k v`.

```
treeInsert :: (Ord k) => (k, v) -> Tree k v -> Tree k v
```

Comment: Alternatively, something like `(Ord a) => a -> Tree a a -> Tree a a`.